# Composite: how to determine active endpoint

Tags: kurento

We used a Composite to create an audio bridge with hubports. We have seen that when the mixing occurs in the composite, if two people talk simultaneously (each a WebRTCEndPoint), the first person is heard and the other voice is suppressed.

How do we determine the endpoint currently used in the mixing (i.e. who is speaking)? Are there events that we can subscribe to or query to find out the active endpoint at any given time?

Answer (score 0):

The Composite mixer takes all the streams (audio and video) at the different inputs and merges them. What you are describing is probably due to the `RTCPeerConnection` in the browser not sending media. That behavious is the same even if you don't use the composite mixer, and there's nothing that we can do about that.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. We believe the RTCPeerConnection is sending audio, but the composite mixer is only picking the first one when multiple people talk at the same time. chrome://webrtc-internals/ shows audio being sent and received.

What is the expected behavior when multiple people talk at the same time? We are seeing first one to talk is used, but is that not what is supposed to happen? If not, how does it mix all the voices? 

Either way, is there a way to tell who is currently talking through some events?